# Adding new data to the top of a UICollectionView without animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, core-animation, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that is displaying data that has been saved locally to the device. Once this data is shown, I call to the server to retrieve any new data.

If the server has new data, I need to insert it at the beginning of the array datasource since it is the newest data. I then need to refresh the `UICollectionView` so that it knows new data has been inserted in the beginning / at the top.

This all works fine, but the problem is that an animation happens and it is noticeable to the user. If the user has scrolled down into some of the cached data, and then the new data is added to the top, the cells they are seeing on screen will reload/animate.

I need to keep all of the above just without the animation. The new cells should be added at the top without changing any of the current cells the user is viewing.

Here is the code I am using to insert and handle the new data:

```
   self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
   var index = 0

   var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
   for newObject in objects {

       // Update datasource
       self.datasource.insert(newObject, atIndex: index)

       // Create index paths for new objects
       let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)

        // Update index
        index += 1
    }

      self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
          }, completion: { (completed) in

                    })
```

I have tried wrapping this code in a UIView animation block with a duration of `0`, in a `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` function, and have also implemented the following in my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass:

```
public override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return nil
    }
```

None of this works. The animation always happens. The cells the user is viewing flash / animate / etc. when the new data is inserted and added.

How can I accomplish this without an animation?

Comment: hello bro..did you solve this problem? if yes please help me out.i am facing same problem